# SFM module for OpenCV on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, opencv, visual-studio-2013, opencv3.1

I already installed OpenCV 3.1 with opencv_contrib on Windows.
Now i want to use the SFM module inside the opencv_contrib, but on the website of the module (http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/db/db8/tutorial_sfm_installation.html) it says "Note: The module is only available for Linux/GNU systems."

Does anyone know if and how i am still able to use it on Windows?

Comment: the dependencies are listed in the link...

Comment: maybe you can compile it as C library (wrapped) with minGW.

Comment: Or could it maybe help applying this "https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/commit/383c158d6e5849fe752e123599362ebd2461ba96?diff=unified" ?

Comment: Okay, unfortunately it didn't help... Has anybody else an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:
http://qiita.com/ChaoticActivity/items/3888e886925ef0f84926.
Here is the english translation:
https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=auto&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fqiita.com%2FChaoticActivity%2Fitems%2F3888e886925ef0f84926&sandbox=1

Comment: Mirnyy, did this work for you? Were you able to run SFM under VS?

Comment: I managed to run sfm with VS2013 using this translated tutorial. I hope it will work for you.